Get TimeZone Display Name Batch Script
Batch code:
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in ('TZUTIL /g') do set TZID=%%a %%b
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=1-4" %%a in ('TZUTIL /L') do (
    set $U=%%a& if "!$U:~0,5!"=="(UTC+" set $TZDN=%%b %%c %%d
    if "%%a %%b %%c %%d"=="!TZID!" set TZDN=!$TZDN!& goto :found
)
:found
echo !TZDN!&pause 
rem TZID=TimeZone ID, TZDN=TimeZone Display Name

I use the code above to get TimeZone DispalyName !TZDN! based on TimeZone ID TZID.
Is there a simpler code to get TimeZone DispalyName ?

This code works for me :
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims=)" %%a in ('wmic timezone get caption /value') do set tzone=%%a
echo %tzone:~1,99%

The timezone value looks like (UTC+xx) yyy zzz.
This code gets the timezone part after )  (excluding the blank).
Reference :
How-to: Extract part of a variable (substring).

I was too focused on TZUTIL, not realizing that there were other commands. Thanks.
